# How many functions $f:A\to A$ are there so that $f(1)=2$ given the set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many functions $f:A\to A$ are there so that $f(1)=2$ given the set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$?

I'm not entirely sure where to start this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. In order to determine such functions you have to decide the value of $f(k)$ for $k=2,3,\dots, 9$ ($8$ values) by choosing it among the $9$ elements of $A$.

Comment: So would I be correct in saying that the value of k is chosen from the set of values for A, and this has to be done 9 times, once for each element of A making the answer 9^9?

Comment: You have 8 choice to make because $f(1)=2$ is already chosen.

Comment: So it would be 1*9^8 then?

Comment: @matthew mcculloch Yes, that's right!

Comment: Thanks for you help, greatly appreciated.